# How to apply tableview cell accessory to a tableview record

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Explanation:**

I have a UITableView that is being populated from JSON. The purpose of the tableview is for the user to select individual row records and have the checkmark accessory appear as a result.

The issue is that while I can get the checkmark to appear for whichever row is selected the checkmark is applied to the row, not the record itself.

For example, if I have two rows in the tableview and I select the first row, a checkmark is applied to it, but after updating the API to remove the row and reloading the tableView the first-row disappears but the checkmark is applied to what was the second record.

**This is what my didSelect method looks like:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    structure = sections[indexPath.section].items
    let theStructure = structure[indexPath.row]
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

}
```

**This is how the structure is defined for the JSON:**

```
struct Section {
    let name : String
    let items : [Portfolios]
}

struct Portfolios: Decodable {
    let code: String
    let maker: String
}
```

Essentially I need help applying the checkmark to the actual record itself not just the static row.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way is to add the `isSelected` information to the data model (`Portfolios`)

```
struct Portfolios : Decodable {
    var isSelected = false

    // other members 
}
```

You might add also `CodingKeys` to exclude `isSelected` from being decoded.

---

In `cellForRowAt` set the checkmark according to `isSelected`

```
let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
```

In `didSelectRowAt` toggle `isSelected` and reload the row

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: When adding `var isSelected : false` to Portfolios struct I get the error: **Type 'Portfolios' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'**

Comment: @JenLarson Because it's a typo, obviously it will be `var isSelected : Bool` or `var isSelected = false`

Comment: There is a minor problem here. `Portfolios` should be a reference type for `toggle()` to work as expected.

Comment: @Desdenova that was actually my second question, how do I set the reference type for toggle?

Comment: @JenLarson Define `Portfolios` as `class` instead of `struct` and this answer will solve your problem.

Comment: It’s a typo. I updated the answer. @Desdenova The code works also with value types.

Comment: Indeed. I'm very confused.

Comment: @Desdenova There is no magic. The value is toggled directly in the data source array so no copy is made.

Comment: @vadian I still get the error Value of type `'Portfolios' has no member 'toggle' `even with the changes applied

Comment: @JenLarson `.items[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()`

Answer (score 0):

First Take an empty array of record and then add checked record to this empty array. In Tableview cellforRow check if a record is in this empty array or not. If it is present in this empty array then display checkmark else remove the checkmark.

Comment: What do you mean by empty array of record?

Comment: take array like this var arrTemp: [Records] = [] and add checked record in this array

Answer (score 0):

Tabelview cells get recycel.
 You need to overwrite prepareForReuse and clear the selected state there.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    isSelected = false
}
```

As for the top answer:
Following the state in your data model is fine too as you set the state for each cel (which solves your problem). 
 **BUT** if you don't need the state other then for deleting entries, then storing the state is pointless. Thing is, all elements in your data model have the state of not selected. So why store an identical information? It is a redundant information that cost you memory for each element. 
 In this case is overriding the prepareForReuse function the best approach.

Comment: There you go. Sorry for late response.