# How to keep checkmarks from disappearing from TableView when scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I currently have a tableView that gets it data from a API that outputs JSON and allows the user to tap to add a checkmark accessory to the right side. The issue I am having is after tapping on a cell in a long list of records and scrolling that row out of view, the checkmark disappears.

This is what I am doing, but when scrolling the checkmarks still disappear when off screen:

```
var selectedIndexPaths: Set<String> = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testcell", 
    for: indexPath)

    if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath.description) {

        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {

        selectedIndexPaths.insert(indexPath.description)
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt 
    indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPaths.remove(indexPath.description)
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Why is the issue still persisting?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519734/how-to-apply-tableview-cell-accessory-to-a-tableview-record/57519887#57519887

Comment: Is my approach entirely incorrect? Some others have recommended it

Comment: An extra array is bad practice. A better – and more efficient – approach is to keep the `selected` information in the model like in the linked answer.