# Index out of range when selecting reusable tableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have the following class to keep track of all of the cells selected in the tableview, the issue is I keep receiving the error Index out of Range on the line:

```
self!.myModels[indexPath.row].isSelected ? self?.selectRow(indexPath) : self?.unselectRow(indexPath)
```

What is causing this? The issue occurs as soon as the tableView loads.

**Rest of the code:**

```
class CheckableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var handler: ((Bool)->())?

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
        handler?(selected) 
            }
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private var myModels: [MyModel] = [MyModel(isSelected: false),MyModel(isSelected: true),MyModel(isSelected: true),MyModel(isSelected: false) ]

var sections = [Section]()
var structure = [Portfolios]()




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CheckableTableViewCell
        cell.handler = {[weak self] selected in
            self?.myModels[indexPath.row].isSelected = selected
        }
        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
                let item = section.items[indexPath.row]
                cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
                cell.selectionStyle = .none

                let titleStr = "\(item.code)
                cell.textLabel!.text = titleStr

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
        myModels[selectedIndexPath].isSelected = true
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

    }
```

**Sections defines the following tableView struct:**

```
struct Section {
    let name : String
    var items : [Portfolios]
}

struct Portfolios: Decodable {

    let code: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case code
    }

}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because your code is too confusing. `myModels` – where the selected information is saved – is not related at all to the data source? You have to put `isSelected` into `Portfolios` (semantically actually `Portfolio`) and consider the sections in `didSelectRow`.

Comment: I honestly really dislike this approach but I can't seem to get a grasp on a much better way of doing all of this. How would you approach this issue from scratch?

Comment: As I said, `isSelected` belongs to `Portfolio` (don't include it in CodingKeys). And the callback is actually not needed, update `isSelected` of the cell in `cellForRow` from the model and change it in `didSelect` / `didDeselect`. Another question is do you really need the color change to indicate the selection or is the checkmark sufficient?

Comment: No a checkmark is sufficient enough

Comment: Did you ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519734/how-to-apply-tableview-cell-accessory-to-a-tableview-record/57519887#57519887)? It looks pretty similar. There is a solution.

Comment: No, I am following a tutorial on tableViews and noticed the checkmarks do not stay with the cell when scrolling. I'd assume they are doing the same

Comment: My solution in the linked question preserves the checkmarks.

Comment: What do you think of the response that overwrites **prepareForReuse** [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519734/how-to-apply-tableview-cell-accessory-to-a-tableview-record/57519887#57519887)

Comment: I will not be using the checkmarks to mark rows for deletion, I just wanted to add checkmarks to the rows and have them stay there. Nothing fancy

Comment: The response misuses `prepareForReuse`. My suggestion does exactly what you want